# How can I see the repository URL to which my working directory is pointed?

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn, switch-statement

I use the switch feature of Subversion quite often, but sometimes I forget where some of my working directories are pointed. Is there a way to easily find out the URL to which my working copy is pointed? Right now, the best way I know how is to right click, and go to the TortoiseSVN repo browser.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can simply go to the file explorer select the folder of which you like to know the repository url select properties and go to the subversion tab folder. And there the information is located or on command line just

```
svn info
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use "SVN Commit..." option for this (you're not obliged really to commit anything).

BTW, command line svn client has info command, i.e. **svn info**.

Answer (score 1):

- right-click, "properties", svn tab
- right-click, "commit", the url is
  shown at the top of the commit dialog
  ("commit to: ")